# How to count columns from within a file

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to count the number of columns from within a txt.file
Example file (*txt_file.txt*):

```
aaron 1 2 3
bethi 1 2 3
dylan 1 2 3
kevin 1 2 3
```

This is my code snippet: (main.c)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//File based variables
char line[1024] = {0x0};
char name[100] = {0x0};
int i, j;

//Array based variables
int students = 0,
    assignments = 0,
    count = 0;

//File pointer, refer to file as fp now.
FILE *fp;
printf("the input file name is %s\n",  argv[1]);
if ( fp == NULL )
{
  puts ( "Cannot open source file");
}

// open file in read mode & get size
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
**get_data_size(fp,&students,&assignments);** //Function returning junk

//MY array for grades
//-------------------------------------------
int **grades = (int **)malloc(assignments * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < assignments; i++)
{
  grades[i] = (int *)malloc(students * sizeof(int));
  if (grades[i] == NULL)
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory to allocate\n");
     exit(1);
  }
}
```

Code snippet for get_data_size function: (Use: find and determine size of file. Rows vs Columns)

```
void get_data_size(FILE *fp, int *students, int *assignments)
{
//File based variables
char line[1024] = {0x0};
char name[100] = {0x0};

while(fgets(line, 1023, fp)) //rows
{
  students++;
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
char delims[] = ",";
char *result = strtok( line, delims );
while( result != NULL )  //columns
{
  assignments ++;
  printf( "result is \"%s\"\n", result );
  result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
//These are what return strange junk.
printf("The number of counts, or columns in the array is: %d\n",&assignments);
printf("The number of lines, or rows in the array is: %d\n",&students);
}
```

Comment: `!feof(fin)` is not a good loop condition. You should use `fgets(line, 1023, fin)` as the condition and remove it from loop body.

Comment: Why did you add so many spaces to the file?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't know how to display the Ex text file the way it should look without using spaces.

Comment: @MikeCAT I implemented your suggestions, is that what you ment? Also, why is !feof bad practice for looping conditions?

Comment: @DancingDylan you're declaring your array as `grades[0][0]`

Comment: @tijko Yeah, but at the end, I run my 2d array through a loop, incrementing [i] to = rows, then [j] to = columns. Should I not do this?

Comment: Try and avoid the use of *magic-numbers* in your code (e.g. `1024`, `1023`, `100`, etc..) If you need a constant `#define` one, or even better for numerical constants, use an `enum` as shown in at the top of my example program (for `MAXC`).

Comment: Thanks, I understand why. I went ahead and implementd a enum within my main

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What my problem is, is filing my array with the values now. I've been trying to use these codes, and editing them and trying to form my own. I always get strange junk.

Comment: Get rid of the `&` sign before `&assignments` and `&students` (`&` means *address of*) You simply want the values `assignments` and `students`. Note: you should be compiling your code with *warnings enabled* `-Wall -Wextra` at minimum -- which would have explained the problem for you. For constants make the `enum` global, e.g. `enum { MAXN = 100, MAXC = 1024 };` (for max-name and max-chars)

Comment: I did use enum now, but the thing is if I remove & from get_data_size it tells me cannot make pointer from int without a cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `strtok()` and `strtok_r()`, it can strip the `"Abc Efg Ghi"` to `"Abc", "Efg", "Ghi"`, and you can count the total column and store `"Abc", "Efg", "Ghi"` in a 2-D array.

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
```

The `strtok()` function returns a pointer to the next "token" in str1, where str2 contains the delimiters that determine the token. `strtok()` returns `NULL` if no token is found. In order to convert a string to tokens, the first call to `strtok()` should have str1 point to the string to be tokenized. All calls after this should have str1 be `NULL`.

Also, you can read the [docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

For example:

```
char str[] = "Abc Efg Ghi";
char delims[] = " ";
char *result = NULL; 
int count = 0;
result = strtok( str, delims );
while( result != NULL ) {
    count ++;
    printf( "result is \"%s\"\n", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
printf("The total column is %d\n", count);
```

The above code will display the following output:

```
result is "Abc "
result is "Efg"
result is "Ghi"
The total column is 4
```

The following code read text from a file named test.csv, and store the data into 2-D array.

test.csv

```
alice, 22, 1992/03/05
bob, 33, 1981/11/21
cart, 40, 1974/07/13
```

readfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *trim(char *str)
{
    char *p = str; 
    while (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t' || *p == '\r' || *p == '\n')
        p ++;
    str = p; 
    p = str + strlen(str) - 1; 
    while (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t' || *p == '\r' || *p == '\n')
        -- p;
    *(p + 1) = '\0'; 
    return str; 
}
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char ** data = (char **)malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
    {
        data[i] = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    }
    char *** mydata = (char ***)malloc(3 * sizeof(char **));
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    {
        mydata[i] = (char **)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j ++)
        {
            mydata[i][j] = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        }
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.csv", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    char line[1024];
    int row = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) 
    {
        //printf("%s", line);

        char *save_ptr;
        char *name = strtok_r(line, ",", &save_ptr);
        if (name == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        //printf("%s\n", save_ptr);
        char *age = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &save_ptr);
        //printf("%s\n", save_ptr);
        char *birthday = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &save_ptr);
        //printf("%s\n", save_ptr);
        strcpy(mydata[row][0], trim(name));
        strcpy(mydata[row][1], trim(age));
        strcpy(mydata[row][2], trim(birthday));
        //printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", trim(name), trim(age), trim(birthday));
        row ++;
    }
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row ++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", mydata[row][0], mydata[row][1], mydata[row][2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function split the `,`, and you can also split the `" "`. You can change the code as your need.

Hope these two function can help you to store your data and get the column number.

Comment: Okay, but what if I'm supposed to use this based on the fact that the strings within a certain file can change? Making rows, and columns all variable based off the size of the file, ect. You have an array called str[] then you fill that with data. How can I get around this, to where we aren't predetermining the info within the file?

Comment: Wow, okay. Got it working properly Thanks alot bud, for a beginner your code was really easy to follow through!

Comment: @DancingDylan, I will edit my code 5 hours later. I am busy now. Sorry. In my view, as a beginner of `C` language, he should know the `API` to make things easier. Good luck

Comment: Is it possible to edit this code in a way that will fill my array[rows][columns] with the info from my file? I feel like I can implement some way to do this, using my code off of what you have shown me. Isn't it just a really simple for loop to fill the array with the file data?

Comment: @DancingDylan, you can edit this code in a way that will fill your array[rows][columns]. And the 2-D array's dimension in my code is 3 and your data is  4. So, you should understand how do I initialize the 2-D array, it is easy to understand. It is simple, but, I think you should understand how it works. Once you understand it, you can do it by yourself later. Good luck, just try!

Comment: So, the code works properly thanks alot! (Sorry for the late reply.) But, I just now implemented my code into a function outside of main, using pointers. For some reason, it returns junk. No warnings or errors, the return values are just bunked. Would you be able to see if you see any scope issues, or decaying arrays when I edit my question?

Comment: @DancingDylan, please don't change question title. This is another question, and if you have another question, just ask a new question in this site. please don't changed the question title, this is another question now. your previous question maybe helpful for some members.

Comment: Okay, didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to count the columns of data in a string is to walk a pointer down the string and check each character. If a non-whitespace character is encountered, increase you count by 1 and then scan to find the next whitespace. Then simply scan forward while the characters continue to be whitespace until you find the next non-whitespace character and (repeat). A quick function that fits that bill could be something like:

```
/** count columns of data in a character string.
 */
int countcol (const char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return 0;    /* validate input */

    char *p = s;    /* pointer to buf */
    int col = 0;    /* initialize col */

    while (*p) { /* for each char in buf */
        /* if p points to non-whitespace, col + 1 */
        if (*p != ' ' && *p != '\t') col++, p++;
        /* skip non-whitespace to find whitespace */
        while (*p && *p != ' ' && *p != '\t') p++;
        /* skip multiple whitespace together */
        while (*p && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t')) p++;
    }
    return col;
}
```

A small sample program that reads information on `stdin` and counts the columns in each line could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXC = 64 };

void rmcrlf (char *str);
int countcol (const char *s);

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    int col = 0;

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* read from stdin    */

        rmcrlf (buf);   /* remove trailing '\n' read by fgets */
        if (!*buf) continue;            /* skip empty line    */
        col = countcol (buf);
        printf ("'%s' (%d-col)\n", buf, col);
    }

    return 0;
}

/** stip trailing newlines and carraige returns by overwriting with
 *  null-terminating char. str is modified in place.
 */
void rmcrlf (char *str)
{
    if (!str || !*str) return;
    char *p = str;
    for (; *p; p++)
        if (*p == '\n' || *p == '\r') { *p = 0; break; }
}

/** count columns of data in a character string.
 */
int countcol (const char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return 0;    /* validate input */

    char *p = s;    /* pointer to buf */
    int col = 0;    /* initialize col */

    while (*p) { /* for each char in buf */
        /* if p points to non-whitespace, col + 1 */
        if (*p != ' ' && *p != '\t') col++, p++;
        /* skip non-whitespace to find whitespace */
        while (*p && *p != ' ' && *p != '\t') p++;
        /* skip multiple whitespace together */
        while (*p && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t')) p++;
    }
    return col;
}
```

(**note:** adjust the constant `MAXC` to meet your input length; also note the `rmcrlf` function simply removes an *carriage-returns* or *line-feeds* (`'\n'`) from the end of the string read by `fgets` by overwriting either character with a `0` (the *nul-terminating* character))

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/text_file.txt
aaron 1 2 3
bethi 1 2 3
dylan 1 2 3
kevin 1 2 3
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/file_count_col <dat/text_file.txt
'aaron 1 2 3' (4-col)
'bethi 1 2 3' (4-col)
'dylan 1 2 3' (4-col)
'kevin 1 2 3' (4-col)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll run though your code and parse it and see if I can manage the data and try to implement it! Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm going to save your code example for a later date. I like your reasoning and how you made it into a function. I';; probably modify the variables and save it in my library for later use!

Comment: Sure, it's posted to help you in any way it can. Feel free to keep it, use it, learn from it, whatever.

Comment: @DancingDylan, note, using any of the `string.h` functions is fine, but that means you must include that header. Many of the string parsing problems in C can be efficiently solved with a simple *pointer*. Learning how to correctly use *pointers* and *pointer arithmetic* to manipulate/parse strings/arrays/structures/etc is the same as being handed the "*keys to the kingdom of C*". While not difficult at all, it takes working with them to really be able to wrap your head around their proper use. Good luck.